# Shared Memory with Microsoft Hekaton

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, memory-optimized-tables

Does the Microsoft SQL Server 2014 In-Memory Engine supports Shared Memory access like Oracle TimesTen? I only found that there was a [protocol with this name in SqlServer2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187892%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)  but i found nothing for SqlServer2014

thanks

Comment: Shared memory is what happens by default [when you connect from the local machine](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187892(v=sql.105).aspx). It has nothing to do with whether your tables are in memory or not, it's just the memory space that the connection uses (again, by default - you can force it or override it).

Comment: Perhaps you could offer some more context as to why you are asking the question of shared memory access?

Answer (score 2):

Hekaton does **not** support direct memory access from client applications. In theory an application could access the same memory space that SQL Server uses using OS memory sections. That is not implemented, though.

The shared memory transport has nothing to do with this. Indeed, it uses a shared memory region to transfer data. But it still runs the normal TDS protocol (including the data conversion and serialization that this involves).

Answer (score 0):

I am not a expert in Hekaton but as per Kalens article Yes it does but in different way from Oracle:

> For processing OLTP data, there are two types of specialized engines.
>   The first are main-memory databases. Oracle has TimesTen, IBM has
>   SolidDB and there are many others that primarily target the embedded
>   DB space. The second are applications caches or key-value stores (for
>   example, Velocity – App Fabric Cache and Gigaspaces) that leverage app
>   and middle-tier memory to offload work from the database system. These
>   caches continue to get more sophisticated and acquire database
>   capabilities,such as transactions, range indexing, and query
>   capabilities (Gigaspaces already has these for example). At the same
>   time, database systems are acquiring cache capabilities like
>   high-performance hash indexes and scale across a cluster of machines
>   (VoltDB is an example). The In-Memory OLTP engine is meant to offer
>   the best of both of these types of engines. One way to think of
>   In-Memory OLTP is that it has the performance of a cache and the
>   capability of a database. It supports storing your tables and indexes
>   in memory, so you can create an entire database to be a complete
>   in-memory system. It also offers high performance indexes and logging
>   as well as other features to significantly improve query execution
>   performance.

Article and download previously available from [this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20131024072125/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2013/10/20/sql-server-2014-in-memory-oltp-hekaton-whitepaper-for-ctp2.aspx).